# Grabbing string value from GridView Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, type-conversion

I was following this tutorial on how to change the color of a GridView Row depending on the value of a specific column: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7ADEYhwqxk
and I can't figure out an alternative for the line:

```
int stock = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
```

This line produces a value for int but I need a value for a string. I've tried using:

```
string cell = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Text);
```

and

```
string cell = (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Text);
```

but neither have worked to grab a specific value from the gridview column and store it in a string.

UPDATE:

```
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
                            DataSourceID="SqlAdmin" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" PageSize="150" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="COMMENT">
                                    <ControlStyle Width="800px" />
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCOMMENT" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COMMENT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="COMMENTtxt" runat="server"
                                            Text='<%# Bind("COMMENT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part #" SortExpression="PART_NO">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PART_NO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="PartNotxt" runat="server"
                                            Text='<%# Bind("PART_NO") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="NOTE">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNOTE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOTE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="NOTEtxt" runat="server"
                                            Text='<%# Bind("NOTE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle Width="500px" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Change color:

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox COMMENTtxt = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("COMMENTtxt");

                if (COMMENTtxt == "x")
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: The Text property should be a string, therefore `string cell = (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Text);` should work. What does the error say when you use this?

Comment: @Crowcoder @Gergő Gutyina I used `Label1.Text = cell` to test and see the output and it is blank.

Comment: See my answer below. For any templated column,  you can't and do not use the cells[] collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is why it's "often" a REALLY good idea to post some of the markup.

Keep this rule in mind:

For data bound fields, auto generated (or not even autogenerated), then you use the .cells[] collection.

However, for templated columns, then you can NOT use cells[] colleciton, but have to use find control.

so, take this example gv:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="60%" > 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descripiton">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />                       
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

We have a "mix" of bound fields (cells collection), and that of some plain jane regular controls (check box, and button, and label for description).

So, when we click a row button, lets grab the check box value (active - a templated control - so "find control"

Lets grab the HotelName (bound field - so cells[] collection)

And lets grab the Description (a label - so again find control).

Code to load is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        LoadData();
}

void LoadData()
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And now we see/have this:

[image]

Ok, so now our row button click, again the button is just a plain jane button with a click event.

The code for the button is thus this:

```
protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

    Debug.Print($"Row index click = {gRow.RowIndex}");

    int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

    Debug.Print($"Data base PK ID = {PK}");

    // get hotel name - bound field - se use cells[]
    Debug.Print($"Hotel name = {gRow.Cells[2].Text}");


    // get check box
    CheckBox chkActive = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkActive");
    Debug.Print($"Value of check box (active) = {chkActive.Checked}");

    // get label with desription
    Label lblDesc = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblDescription");
    Debug.Print($"Descripiton text = {lblDesc.Text}");

}
```

Output:

```
Row index click = 1
Data base PK ID = 5
Hotel name = Inns of Banff
Value of check box (active) = False
Description text = All amenities including pool, hot tub, restaurant, lounge, and beauty services
```

So, note the use of "find control" for templated columns.

Also note VERY close, the use of datakeys. This allows me to get the "hidden" (server side only - for security!!!) the database PK id, but it is NOT exposed in the markup, nor required in the markup, but once I have the row index, then I can get/use/have/enjoy the use of the database PK row value, but never have to include it, nor display it in the GV markup.

## Edit#2: Change some colors in the GV

In my above sample gv, lets say we want to highlight in blue, ONLY the active hotels. We will highlight the HotelName (cells collection), and highlight the description (a label - (have to use findcontrol).

So, in row data bound, we would/could have this code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // get full data bind row - NOT limted to JUST data in GV
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            if ((bool)gData["Active"]) {
                // highlight Hotel (cells colleciton)

                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue;

                // now lbl (description)
                Label lblDescript = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDescription");
                lblDescript.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }
        }
    }
```

and now we see this:

[image]

In fact, for "highlighting", you can use the cells collection, since even controls are placed in those cells. However, the above does show how to get/grab/use controls.

but, for a background color, then we can use cells collection.

Lets lighten up the blue color a bit, and use cells, so then this:

```
            if ((bool)gData["Active"]) {
                // highlight Hotel (cells colleciton)
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am getting an error with the lin `TextBox COMMENTtxt = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("COMMENTtxt");` I have updated my question with some markup. The error says "gRow does not exist in current context" But I'm not sure how to include it in my for loop `for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`

Comment: gRow is a variable that WE created - not one that exists already. And keep in mind, you don't need a loop, since row data bind fires for EACH ROW, and thus see my update as to how we can format controls and text boxes in the gv. So, no loop/for next is required.

Comment: Your response helped me greatly, thank you very much!